# Scrollable Image in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, velocity

Looking for tips/tools to make this happen (using PDF/Velocity Templates/Java):

I have an image that has large dimension (4000 x 2000) and that image is obviously not viewable in a PDF. I can modify the size of the image to fit into the PDF.

But what I want to do is to view the actual size of the image in the PDF. I want to be able to scroll the image from left to right.

How can I keep the true size of the image, without destroying the set container size of the PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite a basic PDF feature, but it might be implementable using some embedded scripts inside the PDF, assuming that the user has a PDF viewer capable of running scripts.

Now, a PDF is not supposed to be used as a dynamic document where you can scroll. How would that work on paper after printing? If you want scrollable documents, then you should stick to HTML. I strongly advise you not to try to do this.

If, however, you still want to go down this route, then here are a couple of suggestions:

1. As I said, you could do it with embedded JavaScript, but then it depends on how you're generating the PDF: FOP, iText, another PDF writer library, or just plain `println` concatenation, since few libraries support embedding JavaScript.
2. You could just make the image fit into the page, but keep its original resolution, so that you end up with a high resolution page that the user can zoom in and scroll. This way you leave the scrolling to the PDF viewer itself, you'll just have to let the user know that the image has a higher resolution and should be magnified. And frankly 4000px isn't that large, it's not even enough to keep up with today's standard printer DPIs.

Comment: I actually decided to use PDFBox to add a custom sized page to a pre-existing PDF based on the image's width and height from BufferReader. Thanks for the tips!